# Using susy with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, susy

Is it possible to use Susy with Jekyll? If so, how?

I tried adding 'susy' to my Gemfile and `bundle install`'ing, then adding susy to my `gems` array in `config.yml`:

```
// _config.yml
...
gems:
  - 'jekyll-compass'
  - 'susy'
```

and following the instructions in [Jekyll's docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss), placing `@import 'susy'` in my `/css/style.scss` file. However, I get an error:

> File to import not found or unreadable: susy.

Answer (score 2):

`jekyll-compass` lets you configure Compass. There's more info in its readme, but for susy I just needed to add a `_data/compass.yml` file, and add

```
require:
  - susy
```

to it.

Also, `jekyll-compass` expects your main entry `style.scss` to be under `_sass`, not `css` (like Jekyll's out of the box sass support does). I'm sure this is configurable as well.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to keep style.scss under css folder and not _sass?

Comment: no :/ you can see my project here: https://github.com/samselikoff/samselikoff.github.io

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! How come you've deleted your [dir configurations](http://i.imgur.com/0OAg3Im.png) in your compass.yml file??

Comment: I think I just went with the defaults and put my stylesheets in _compass?? honestly I can't remember right now lol

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install susy with bower, you can just symlink the files under `bower_components/susy/sass` to the `_sass` directory (`ln -s bower_components/susy/sass/* _sass`. I have a fairly minimal working example [on GitHub](https://github.com/dlab-berkeley/dlab-berkeley.github.io/commit/23db856e57a640a0ba1b473563aed6977f680082).

The CSS is generated properly and served [here](http://dlab-berkeley.github.io/css/dlab.css) for now (though that link will *hopefully* rapidly become out of sync with the git commit referenced above).